# How to automatically check PR for more than one commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I am setting up a CI/CD pipeline for a BitBucket repository. So far, I've been able to set up Jenkins to to build a Docker image each time there is a PR, which will then show up as a success or failed status under "Builds" next to the PR like this:

[image]

As a team, we have a rule for only merging single commit PRs --meaning the developer needs to squash their commits into one single commit using something like `git rebase`. I want to see a pass or fail status somewhere indicating that the PR has multiple commits and needs to be squashed. Right now we just look at the commits and reject anything with more than one commit, but it would be nice if merging was prevented for PRs with multiple commits or at least show a pass or fail like the above screenshot.

I know BitBucket has something called "Merge Checks". Is that what I'm looking for? If so, how do I configure it? If not, would I do this in Jenkins? If so, how?

Ultimately, my question is this: How can I configure this repository or the Jenkins pipeline to check for multiple commits when a PR is submitted?

Comment: I check in code in stages as I'm working, then send a PR when I'm done. That PR can contain 1 - N commits on that branch. In Gitlab, there's an option to `squash` multiple commits into one during a merge. Maybe that's what you want with BitBucket? https://bitbucket.org/blog/git-squash-commits-merging-bitbucket

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno that's a good resource --I did not know about the merge squash option. Now I'm wondering why many developers consider rebasing a best practice for clean commit history when merge squash does essentially the same thing.